# Fatal Error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(realm:schema:)'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

### My Issue:

- Yesterday, I updated my `Realm` framework from `0.91.5` to `0.92.0` for my project (written in Swift). I found that the Realm Team had already separated `Swift` part and `Objective-C` part from the previous entire Cocoa Framework, the team also change the syntax. And I already corrected my code as the latest Realm syntax, but I still got some trouble with `init()`.

### The Error:

- The Compiler thrown the error: `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer init(realm:schema:) for CardModel`.
- The thing is this error did not occur with the previous version of `Realm`.
- I used `MultiPeer Connectivity` framework for project, which means I need to `Encode` and `Decode` for exchanging of data.
- I tried to change or add other `init()` to `CardModel`, but it did not work.

### My Code:

```
import RealmSwift

class CardModel: Object {
dynamic var cardID: String = ""
dynamic var firstName: String = ""
dynamic var lastName: String = ""
dynamic var userImage = NSData()
dynamic var status: String = ""
dynamic var cardType: Int = 1
dynamic var cardDate = NSDate()

override init() {
    super.init()
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    self.userImage = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("userImage") as! NSData
    self.cardID = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardID") as! String
    self.firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as! String
    self.lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as! String
    self.status = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("status") as! String
    self.cardType = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardType") as! Int
    self.cardDate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardDate") as! NSDate
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.userImage, forKey: "userImage")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.cardID, forKey: "cardID")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.status, forKey: "status")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.cardType, forKey: "cardType")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.cardDate, forKey: "cardDate")
  }  
}
```

Please teach me how to solve this problem.

A big appreciation for your guide and time.

Ethan Joe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran in the same problem the other day:

Basically you should not create "init" methods but you can create "convenience init" methods. In that case you can't call super.init() but you call something like self.init()

so in your case above you have to remove override init() and the other init can be:

```
convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    self.userImage = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("userImage") as! NSData
    self.cardID = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardID") as! String
    self.firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as! String
    self.lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as! String
    self.status = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("status") as! String
    self.cardType = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardType") as! Int
    self.cardDate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cardDate") as! NSDate
}
```

More information: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849

Comment: And it still need to add the `required` between `convenience` and `init( )`

Comment: Ok thanks for that remark i updated my code to add the `required` to help future readers

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the init like that:

```
init(object:schema:) {   
    super.init(object: object, schema: schema) 
}
```

There are various posts on [github about that](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1101).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will correct it when I home.

Comment: Hi, I still got some troubles after I added new `init( )` in my CardModel Class.  1. For `init(object: ?, schema: ?), what are Parent Classes` should `object` and `schema` inherit ? 2. For `super.init(object: object, schema: schema)`, I guess the left `object` is not equal to the right one, right?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing to add:

```
required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}
```