# Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' when calling Realm().objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to retrieve a Realm's objects by using

```
Realm(path: Realm.defaultPath).objects(Fruits)
```

this what I get in result:

```
12: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' for class DB.Fruits
```

The object has only the following init:

```
required init() {
        super.init()
        nextPrimaryKey()
    }
```

I've gone through all the information about the init()s issues, however none of them solved the problem (including this [almost-exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090603/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initrealmschema)). Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding the init [is now supported](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849#issuecomment-144792835). However, you may run into this issue when using a `convenience init` as the designated initializer if you override the `required init`. This can be fixed by *removing* the `required init`.

For example:

```
required init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.init()

    // custom init work
}
```

Should become:

```
convenience init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.init() // still calling self.init(), not super.init()

    // custom init work
}
```

Comment: Great answer with corresponding link to realms github site. Oughta be the accepted answer. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`RealmSwift.Object` does not currently support subclasses adding new required initializers, only `convenience` initializers. More details about initializers and what's not yet supported can be found at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849.